# Call function from a class

Tags: python, tkinter

So I did do research on this and found out a couple methods to do this but for some reason everytime I try to do it, it just doesnt work out for me and I am hoping if someone will be able to help me. For my program I currently have a message box pop up first which is the code I just gave but what I am looking to do is take the text from the message box which will be the file name and pass it to a function outside the class so it can open the file. Thanks

```
class MyDialog:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)
        top.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        Label(top, text="Enter File Name").pack()

        self.textboxpopup = Entry(top)
        self.textboxpopup.pack(padx=5)

        popupButton = Button(top, text="Submit", command=self.popUpinfo)
        popupButton.pack(pady=5)

    def popUpinfo(self):
        startfilename = self.textboxpopup.get()
        self.top.destroy()
        return startfilename

def read_file():
    startfilename = MyDialog(root).popUpinfo()
    print(startfilename)

    openfile = open(startfilename + ".txt")
    lines = openfile.read().split('\n')
    lines = [l.split(',') for l in lines]

    return lines
```

Comment: So if I understand this right, you are not getting the filename in the line `startfilename = MyDialog(root).popUpinfo()`?

Comment: no Im not, when I tried print(startfilename) to test if it will print, nothing printed out

Comment: Okay, try printing in the `popUpinfo` function itself. I'm sure the line itself isn't returning an empty string. That could probably mean that there is some setup error which isn't letting you get the input from the popup.

Comment: I did that already and it did print so it must be returning something

Comment: Alright, so when printing in the function you are getting the proper text, but not when calling it in your read_file method. Right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: You are not calling `read_file` anywhere in this code. How are you calling that function?

Comment: I didnt post the full code on

Comment: Problem is, `MyDialog(root)` will create a _new_ instance of `MyDialog` and initially, `Entry` has no value in it (it's _just_ created) and you are trying to get the value from `Entry` right after it's created.

Comment: Yes the code needs to wait until the callback is fired to indicate some text has been entered.

Comment: But when I print(startfilename) right after I destoy self.top.destroy() it does print something so it must be returning something